# QR Code manipulation using Python (jython) - Scaling and removing Quiet Zone

Tags: python, jython, jes

Having trouble with this particular task (using JES 4.3). The task is to scale down a QR code image using Python to a 25 x 25 image, and to remove the white border (quiet zone) from the image. I have no trouble scaling it down, but the removal of the quiet zone is troubling. I believe it must be done before the scaling itself, and the quiet zone width can vary. Thus it appears that I need to remove each outer layer of pixels one by one until the program detects that its no longer the quiet zone. Quite sure a while loop is required, but have no clue how to implement that effectively. My code so far:

```
def reduce(qrPicture):
  file = makePicture(qrPicture)
  myPicture = duplicatePicture(file)


  width = getWidth(myPicture)
  height = getHeight(myPicture)



  newPicture = makeEmptyPicture(25, 25)
  newWidth = getWidth(newPicture)
  newHeight = getHeight(newPicture)

  basePixel = getPixelAt(myPicture, 0, 0)
  startX = 0
  startY = 0

  xWidth = width/float(newWidth)
  yHeight = height/float(newHeight)


  for x in range(startX, newWidth):
    for y in range(startY, newHeight):
      smallPix = getPixel(newPicture, x, y)

      pixelX = x*xWidth;
      pixelY = y*yHeight;


      oPixel = getPixel(myPicture, int(pixelX), int(pixelY))
      setColor(smallPix, getColor(oPixel))
```

As mentioned, this simply scales the image to 25 x 25 but does not remove the quiet zone. Can someone tell me how to implement this removal of the quiet zone? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def findQuietZone(pic):
   width = getWidth(pic)
   height = getHeight(pic)

   for x in range(0, width):
      for y in range(0, height):
         px = getPixel(pic, x, y)
         color = getColor(px)
         if (colour != white):
            value = getX(px)

   quietZone = width - value
```